# How to install Ping Tunnel on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, cygwin

I want to install ptunnel on Windows, but this error appears:

> `>ptunnel.exe -v 4 -c "DeviceNPF_{3C96EE3D-B603-4846-9E3D-2D5926AEB9A3}"
>         2 [main] ptunnel 14292 find_fast_cwd: WARNING: Couldn't compute FAST_CWD pointer.  Please report this problem to
>   the public mailing list cygwin@cygwin.com
>   [inf]: Enable pcap Mode using device: DeviceNPF_{3C96EE3D-B603-4846-9E3D-2D5926AEB9A3}
>   [inf]: Starting ptunnel v 0.62.
>   [inf]: (c) 2004-2005 Daniel Stoedle, daniels@cs.uit.no - Windows Port by michu / www.neophob.com
>   [inf]: HINT: start ptunnel with "-h" parameter to view help and Windows WinPcap devices
>   [inf]: Forwarding incoming ping packets over TCP.
>   [dbg]: Starting ping proxy..
>   [dbg]: Creating icmp datagram socket..
>   [inf]: Initializing pcap.
>   [err]: ERROR: Error opening adapter: L▒op▒ration a r▒ussi. (0)
>   [inf]: Ping proxy is listening in privileged mode.
>     33492 [main] ptunnel 14292 exception::handle: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
>     86091 [main] ptunnel 14292 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to ptunnel.exe.stackdump`

I think that it's problem of cygwin. Can you help me please ?

Comment: Are you installing it or running it ? it seems to me that you are doing the later, "ptunnel.exe -v 4 -c"

Comment: " Please report this problem to the public mailing list cygwin@cygwin.com" as instructed

Comment: http://neophob.com/2007/10/pingtunnel-for-windows-icmp-tunnel/ this the tuto that i use it

Comment: i reportet it but Hi. This is the qmail-send program at sourceware.org.
I'm afraid I wasn't able to deliver your message to the following addresses.
This is a permanent error; I've given up. Sorry it didn't work out.

Comment: `find_fast_cwd: WARNING: Couldn't compute FAST_CWD` means the program is using an obsolete cygwin1.dll, as this problem was solved several years ago

Comment: Also, which version of Windows are you using?  7, or 10?  Please remove the irrelevant tag.

Comment: @matzeri so what do i do !! have a resolution of this problem

Comment: @pak windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest version of Ping Tunnel, instead of an outdated version.  [Ping Tunnel 0.72](http://www.cs.uit.no/~daniels/PingTunnel/#download)